# Android network printers discovery: NullPointerException

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi, service-discovery

This question does sound strange, but I never experienced this before. I'm working on network printer application and use NsdManager to discover printers in the WiFi network. It had been working fine for last two weeks, discovering and resolving printers in the same WiFi network. But all of a sudden I started getting the following exception every time I initiate discovery:

```
06-03 15:38:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16849): FATAL EXCEPTION: NsdManager
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.net.nsd.NsdManager$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(NsdManager.java:328)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I'm testing app on Nexus S. I connected Samsung S3 and I don't get this error there. I've searched for this issue, but I couldn't find any workarounds. The closest I got is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39583

Can anybody suggest a solution for this? I tried to change "_ipp._tcp" to "_ipp._udp", but it doesn't let me find any printers in the network.

Comment: Turns out that rebooting the phone actually solves this problem. At least for a while.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Of note, in this demo project when they init things there is this commented out line // mNsdManager.init(mContext.getMainLooper(), this);

Comment: What is happening is that there are no listeners registered to send the message. So when it tries to grab a listener to do this it gets a null on the listener. The weird thing is I should have listeners so I'll submit an answer what's I nail this down.