# Android `getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE)` takes a very long time

Tags: android, applicationcontext, network-service

Android call to `applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE)` takes a very long time. Sometimes it returned after about 1 minute and other times a lot more.

Any idea what's the issue here?

Comment: Happened to me on a SGS4 device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restarting the phone did the trick.

It's still an issue, because requesting users to restart their phone is bad experience.

Comment: Had the same prob. Here's a suggestion that it's our code that crashed the service, after which it never gets up: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19033128/207791
So there's a hope that after we debug our listeners, this won't happen again.